# How to loop through array of database rows, and select the first with desired value?

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array of fields (not rows!) I want to loop through, in a table, in a predefined order, backwards (alternatively, I could reverse the order of the array) and return the field name of the first field that returns a predefined value.

For example, the fields are like this:

```
field_a => 1
field_b => 0
field_c => 1
field_d => 0
field_e => 0
```

And say, field_c was the first with the value I was looking for, even though field_a may already possess the value. What is the best way to loop through e through a, and stopping at c when it's the first field with the value, and returning that field name?

I am working with PHP and MySQL, so I would prefer the returned field name to be a string, not an array - I don't need the value of the row();, only the field name itself.

Thank you! :)

Comment: Your requirements are contradictory: at the top you're saying you need the row name and value, but at the bottom you're saying you only need the row name.  Which is it?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "row name"? The row's primary key? Also, you way want to read over this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/simonince/archive/2009/03/30/procedural-versus-set-based-sql.aspx - even though it's about SQL Server - it discusses how when working with databases you should start thinking of things as set based (vs procedural which is how most programming works).

Comment: By row name, I mean the field name. Let me edit my original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this work?

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE criteria-for-property
ORDER BY whatever-ordering-you-want
LIMIT 1
```

This would retrieve 1 row and then stop.

Comment: Which, if you read the question carefully, is what he asks for. He says "That value" and "return the row name and value of the first row that returns a predefined value.".

Comment: Added for clarity; I want the returned field name.